# Ruby: Why are no dots showing when I run tests with Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I'm playing around with Ruby's `Test::Unit::TestCase`, and though my tests will run, pass, fail, etc. I'm not seeing the dots outputted for each test-case. Is this a configuration I need to set, or a level of verbosity I need to specify?

I'm running Ruby 2.1.0p0

For reference, here's the code I'm working with. It's from a Destroy All Software screencast where the exercise is to build rspec from scratch (not the whole thing, of course):

The tests:

```
#test_spec.rb

require 'test/unit'
require_relative 'spec'


class TestDescribe < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_that_it_can_pass
    describe 'some thing' do
      it 'has some property' do
      end
    end
  end

  def test_that_it_can_fail
    assert_raise(IndexError) do
      describe 'some failing thing' do 
        it 'fails' do
          raise IndexError
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


class TestAssertion < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_that_it_can_pass
    2.should == 2
  end

  def test_that_it_can_fail
    assert_raise(AssertionError) do
      1.should == 2
    end
  end
end
```

And the code:

```
#spec.rb

def describe(description, &block)
  ExampleGroup.new(block).evaluate!
end


class ExampleGroup
  def initialize(block)
    @block = block
  end

  def evaluate!
    instance_eval(&@block)
  end

  def it(description, &block)
    block.call
  end
end


class Object
  def should
    DelayedAssertion.new(self)
  end
end

class DelayedAssertion
  def initialize(subject)
    @subject = subject
  end

  def ==(other)
    raise AssertionError unless @subject == other
  end
end


class AssertionError < Exception
end
```

The output when run with `ruby test_spec.rb`

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

Finished tests in 0.004410s, 907.0295 tests/s, 453.5147 assertions/s.
4 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
```

Comment: By default it should show dots for passes, E for errors and F for failures. Can you post your output and maybe one of your tests including your test_helper?

Answer (score 0):

I think a `TestCase` represents a single test.  It's not responsible for running, or providing a UI.  I think you're looking for a "runner".  In minitest, you can simply `require 'minitest/autorun'`, and in `Test::Unit` (which is deprecated), you'd probably use `Test::Unit::Runner` somehow.  I use `rspec` so I don't know the exact details, but both Test::Unit and minitest are included in ruby stdlib so the documentation should be easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded 'test-unit' and I got the dots back. At the moment of writing this the version is 3.1.8.